# Why does calling eval without a block terminate this Perl program?

Tags: perl, eval

The following program stops at the 2nd call to eval. Is that expected? I read [perldoc -f eval](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) and am surprised that the output of print "2: ..." is not displayed.

```
eval {die("The curly braces seem to rescue me! Life moves on")};
print "1: $@\n";
eval die("Program actually terminates here! Subsequent prints are not shown");
print "2: $@\n";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`perldoc -f eval`

> ```
> eval EXPR
> eval BLOCK
> eval    In the first form, often referred to as a "string eval", the
>         return value of EXPR is parsed and executed as if it were a little
>         Perl program.
> ```

… so `die` is called and then the string it returns is evaluated.

… except it doesn't return a string. It makes the program die so `eval` is never called.

Comment: Quentin, thank you. I misunderstood that eval in general would always get a result from EXPR, including catching any fatal error. Obviously, that's not the case for str eval.

Comment: I notice the following paragraph from perldoc -f eval: "If there is a syntax error or runtime error, or a die statement is executed, eval returns undef in scalar context or an empty list in list context..." I found this paragraph misleading because it seems to suggest that a program should always continue after eval() (str or block). Am I again misunderstanding something here?

Comment: @Ltf4an — (1) The expression executes as normal (2) The return value (expected to be a string) is passed to `eval`. (3) `eval` evaluates that string. The rule you quote applies during step 3, which you never reach in your example.

Comment: Your explanation in concrete steps is excellent, and I completely got it. I think it's much better than the documentation. Do you know how I can request to have it updated?